# SQL Server DB Restore Unable to browse directory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, restore, file-system

I have a problem with SQL Server 2008.
When I try to restore a backup (located in the default location). This error appears.

> Cannot access the specified path of file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges and tha the path or file exists.

I've tried to google about this error but nothing has been resolved, I've also tried to assign the folder Full Access to Everyone and the error still appears.

The SQL Server services (Engine and Agent) are running under the NetworkService system account.

However in the folder browser window I can browse through the C:\ drive

**Edit:**
The server is standalone, I have only one with Windows Server 2008 x86 as a domain controller.

Comment: did you restart the server process after granting folder permission?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check is that:

Has the SQL Server service account been added as a member of any local
groups on EACH server? Does the group in which it resides have read-write
permissions?

So please check if you're NW service account is admin on the box, along with R/W permissions for it to access the folder for backups.

Also, in case you are on cluster,

then you need to make sure and check for the dependency of that drive when in cluster for the service account its running under!

Comment: I didn't add the SQL Server service account to any local groups. I've only a standalone server (Domain Controller). The backup folder has the Network Service account with a full control. (Inherited from the parent folder, installed by SQL Setup and never touched by me)

Comment: You added a DC to the network? Or as an added function to the SQL Server?